# Having an issue with preg_match() in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am a bit rusty at PHP, so bear with me. I am making a simple email form that validates a few key pieces of data. One of these fields is the submitter's zip code. To validate this, I figured a regex would be simple since I am pretty confident the validation can be done in one line. Behold:

```
preg_match("^([0-9]{5}|[0-9]{5}\-[0-9]{4})$", $zip);
```

This should be working to match 12345 and 12345-6789. However, this does not happen. What am I overlooking here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Missing delimiters:

```
preg_match("/^([0-9]{5}|[0-9]{5}\-[0-9]{4})$/", $zip);
```

Comment: Apparently so. Delimiters always mess with me in PHP. Thanks for the quick response :)